# How to use one interface theme with other text-color theme in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, themes, visual-studio-code

I'm currently using Material Theme (Dark High Contrast) in Visual Studio Code, I really like how the interface looks like, although the color highlighting isn't that great since it uses a lot of red for main elements which I don't like. I tried out Cobalt2 by WesBos and it was the opposite, the text colors worked just right, everything really understandable but I don't like that blueish interface, just doesn't feel ok for me.

How could I wether implement an own theme by grapping the interface of Material Theme and the color highlight of Cobalt2, or simply join together these two.

Not planning on making an theme out of that, it's just a personal choice :)

Thank you stranger!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `command palette` : `Developer: Generate Color Theme From Current Settings`

You can copy `"colors"` from one theme to yours `"workbench.colorCustomizations"` in `settings.json`. Perhaps some colors will be absent, use your imagination or whatnot...

Related feature request: [Separate workbench theme and syntax theme](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25986)

Workbench colors reference
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference